# While loop does not seem to loop over after 1 iteration

Tags: python, list, while-loop

G'day. I am new to coding and python.

My goal is to try to create a code where if the element in y reaches the next 0, all the 0 to n (before the next zero) will become n. A sample output should look like this after executing the code below:

```
y = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

# I am interating over two inputs. y_1 = y[1:] and append 0 at the end.
y_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0]

expected output:
x = [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
```

The problem I'm facing I believe comes from the while loop not looping over after `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` is deleted from the list as specified in the code below (which logically to me should loop over?) :

```
y = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0]

x = []

while len(y):
    for i, j in zip(y, y_1):
        if i > j:
            z = i
        
            for k in range(z+1):
                x.append(y[i])
            
            del y[0:z+1]
            del y_1[0:z+1]
    
        elif i == j:
            z = 0
            
            x.append(z)
            
            del y[z]
            del y_1[z]
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You shouldn't delete from a list that you're iterating over.

Comment: y_1, in this code, is y[1:] with 0 append at the end

Comment: don't use `del` because this changes list which you use in `for`-loop - `zip(y, y_1)` - and it can stop it before you expect. Besides, you don't need to delete it to get expected result. And remove `while len(y)` - you also don't need it.

Comment: shorter `y_1 = y[1:] + [0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you use `del` and `while` because you should get expected result doing

```
y   = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y_1 = y[1:] + [0]

x = []

for i, j in zip(y, y_1):
    if i > j:
        z = i
        for k in range(z+1):
            x.append(y[i])
    elif i == j:
        z = 0
        x.append(z)

print(x)
```

In Python you shouldn't delete element from list which you use as `for`-loop because when it delete element then it moves other elements in list used as `for`-loop and it can give unexpected results.
If you really want to run it in some `while len(y)` then you should rather create new list with elements which you want to keep. Or you should duplicate list - `y_duplicated = y.copy()` - and delete in duplicated list and after `for`-loop replace original list `y = y_duplicated`

Comment: Thanks! this helped solve my problem. :) My logic around was to remove the elements so the index should start fresh at 0. Hence, using a while loop until the original list is empty. I was not aware of the unexpected results when deleting a list in a loop action.